# What is the difference between identity server 4 open id connect and Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net, azure, identityserver4, openid-connect

What I know about IdentityServer and OpenID connect is:

The IdentityServer is a free, open source OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core. That incorporates all the protocol implementations and extensibility points needed to integrate token-based authentication, single-sign-on and API access control in your applications.

Further more OpenID Connect is a simple identity layer built on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. OAuth 2.0 defines mechanisms to obtain and use access tokens to access protected resources, but they do not define standard methods to provide identity information. OpenID Connect implements authentication as an extension to the OAuth 2.0 authorization process. It provides information about the end user in the form of an id_token that verifies the identity of the user and provides basic profile information about the user.

What I want to know is what is Azure Active Directory and How it is works? Did we use Azure AD with openid connect? or it is optional with openid connect? and If I've an webapi which is based on ASP.Net core 2.0 with identityserver 4. Did we deploy on azure without implement Azure AD? I m confused because I've an webapi project and a client project based on angular. when I deploy my client project as a new web app on azure its running fine. But when I deploy my web api on azure its not working. Means after deploying my web api when I do post request to get a token or when I want to register a user through my azure web api link it shows me 500 error in postman.

After facing this problem I post it on [Here Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235511/how-to-host-and-deploy-asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-on-azure) but didn't find any helpful answers. So I again start searching and found that if we want to use openid connect with azure we must implement Azure AD. Here is the [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code). So in this question I want to know the difference between openid connect and Azure AD? and second question is. Is this possible to use openid connect without using Azure AD? Please explain your answer briefly. Thanks